# Conducting macro-level OLS regression using aggregated data with few level 1 observations

Tags: least-squares, multilevel-analysis, aggregation

I am currently conducting a study where the outcome variable is measured only at the level 2/group level. The dependent variable is a measure of the proportion of all municipal spending that is being spent on a particular type of service. However, I would like to investigate to what extent this corresponds to the attitudes that municipal residents have about such spendings. For this purpose I make use of individual-level survey data. Unfortunately the survey data available to me is a national sample, and thus does not take the clustring of residents into municipalities into consideration. Meaning that municipalities with a small population also have a small number of respondents in the sample.

In total I have >250 observations of municipalities (level 2). However, the cluster size (the number of respondents for each municipality) ranges from 1 to 160.

My approach is to aggregate the individual-level data, using averages, to the municipal level and then run OLS regression (in accordance with guidelines provided by [Foster-Johnson and Kromey, 2018](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-018-1025-8)). My gut feeling is that even though the municipal averages in terms of attitudes will not be accurately asses for each specific municipality, the relationship between the municipal average attitude toward spending (on XYZ) and the municipal proportion of spending (on XYZ) should be accurate, considering the fair number of observations at the municipal level.

I build this thinking on the principle of reversion to mediocricy, applied to the true relationship between municipal average of attitudes and municipal proporition of spending. Am I wrong to assume this? And is there any litterature that adresses this particular problem, of aggregating from scarce level-1 data and then running a wholly macro-level analysis to predict a level-2 outcome? (I have searched for quite some time now, but I generally only find papers adressing sparseness of data in multilevel modeling).